# Disable flush image cache button in the backend in magento2

Tags: magento2, cache, image, magento-2.2.5

Go to Admin > System > Cache Management

I want to disable flush image cache button in backend given Which is highlighted in bellow image for security purpose.

Can anyone give me solution.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For all user or specific user

Comment: @AmitBera For all user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just directly remove this button, but you can remove access to this button

> Goto System -> Permissions -> User Roles

Open the role that you want to edit

Under **"Additional Cache Management"** you will find **"Catalog Images Cache"** disable it from here

**But if you still want to remove this button, you need to override it's phtml file**

Add new xml file in `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_cache_index.xml`

code in this file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Cache\Additional" name="cache.additional" template="Vendor_Module::system/cache/additional.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="permissions" xsi:type="object">Magento\Backend\Block\Cache\Permissions</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And add your phtml file in your module in: `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/system/cache/additional.phtml` use code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Cache\Permissions|null $permissions */
$permissions = $block->getData('permissions');
?>
<?php if ($permissions && $permissions->hasAccessToAdditionalActions()): ?>
    <div class="additional-cache-management">
        <?php if ($permissions->hasAccessToFlushCatalogImages()): ?>
            <h2>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Additional Cache Management')); ?></span>
            </h2>
            <?php /* ?><p>
                <button onclick="setLocation('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getCleanImagesUrl()); ?>')" type="button">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Flush Catalog Images Cache')); ?>
                </button>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Pregenerated product images files')); ?></span>
            </p><?php */ ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($permissions->hasAccessToFlushJsCss()): ?>
            <p>
                <button onclick="setLocation('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getCleanMediaUrl()); ?>')" type="button">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache')); ?>
                </button>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Themes JavaScript and CSS files combined to one file')) ?></span>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!$block->isInProductionMode() && $permissions->hasAccessToFlushStaticFiles()): ?>
            <p>
                <button onclick="setLocation('<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getCleanStaticFilesUrl()); ?>')" type="button">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Flush Static Files Cache')); ?>
                </button>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Preprocessed view files and static files')); ?></span>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am not able to find "Additional Cache Management"

Comment: System > User Roles > Role Resources

Comment: Please recheck try search of your browser, https://www.screencast.com/t/nQmbQvSXO5S

Comment: Can u give me another solution to disable button

Comment: Sure, let me try

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Thanks its working

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it is helpful to you, your post is still open, you need to mark correct

Comment: Thanks Parthavi. +1 on your question